# Get shortest circle path without repeating any nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I need a query that will get me the shortest circle path between nodes (so if there are multiple paths just returns the shortest one). In addition, these paths shouldn't contain repeated nodes. Examples:

[image]

In this case, if I pass "Item B" as input, I should receive the path "Item B -> Item C -> Item E -> Item B" since the other path "Item B -> Item C -> Item A -> Item C -> Item E - Item B" not only is longer but also contains repeated nodes (Item C)

Using the same picture, if I pass "Item A" as input, I should receive the path "Item A -> Item C  -> Item A"

In addition, it would be nice if the response could include all the nodes involved, without repeating the starting and final node that is the same in all cases.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
MATCH (n:Node{id:"a"})
MATCH p=(n)-[*..20]->(n)
WITH p, length(p) as len
ORDER by len ASC LIMIT 1
UNWIND nodes(p) as node
RETURN distinct node
```

Not sure how well it scales though, note that I added a filter that checks for paths only 20 or fewer hops away.

Comment: This would find paths that do not reuse the same relationship, but it could still find paths that reuse the same node (as long as different relationships are used).

Comment: Given OP requirement for a directed graph solution, I think this is fine.